# Accessing Nested List with user input for plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, user-input

How to get values from below list through input function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplt as plt

List=[['China',25.5,26,27]['Germany',25,30.66,40]] 
Years=['1999','2000']
y=input("Get Country Value:")
if y in List:
   List2=List[y]
List2.plot(Years,y)
plt.show()`
```

Need Output Like

```
Enter Country Name: China
plot with respect to year
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I want to point out some mistakes in this question. Then I will explain two ways in which this can be implemented.

Your `import` has to be modified slightly as the correct syntax is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.
Your `List` variable has to be implemented correctly. `List=[['China',25.5,26,27],['Germany',25,30.66,40]]`(Use `Comma` in between)

Now , I am assuming that you are planning to `plot` `Years` with the values in the `List`, corresponding to the country name given as `input`. However, the sizes do not match. I have taken liberty to add one more value in the `Years`.

First implementation look as shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

List=[['China',25.5,26,27],['Germany',25,30.66,40]] 
Years=['1999','2000',"2001"]
y=input("Get Country Value:")

for i in List:
    if y in i:
        List2 = i[1:]

plt.plot(Years,List2)
plt.show()
```

This can be improved a bit by using a different data structure for your `List` variable. That is `dictionary`. If you haven't had the idea about dictionaries, you can read more about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Implementation of that would look something like below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

List_as_dict = {"China":[25.5,26,27],
                "Germany":[25,30.66,40]
                }
Years=['1999','2000',"2001"]

y=input("Get Country Value:")

plt.plot(Years,List_as_dict[y])
plt.show()
```

This will eliminate unnecessary loop and will be little faster when you are dealing with very big data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the value in your list is total respect of each years. So for visualize the data, I will using plt.bar more than plt.plot . so I try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [['China',25.5,26,27],['Germany',25,30.66,40]]
years = ['1999','2000','2001']

labels = np.arange(len(years))
y = str(input('Input Country Name: '))

for i in data:
    if i[0] == y:
        newdata = i[1:len(i)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(labels, newdata,label=y)
ax.set_title('Total Respect For '+y+' Per Years')
ax.set_ylabel('Value')
ax.set_xticks(labels)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)
plt.show()
```

and the result is:

```
Input Country Name: Germany
```

[image]